# Python GUI for sudoku

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pygame

What would be the bast way to make a GUI for Sudoku? I already made a GUI in Pygame with: buttons, number input to cell, grid display; but it doesn't feel right to draw grid and buttons 30 times per second even when nothing is changing. Is there any better way?

Comment: What is your definition of "better" in this context? What's wrong with drawing everything multiple times per seconds for a simple game like this?

Comment: It feels like its unnecessary and i would like to know if there are easier/more efficient ways to do it for future projects.

Comment: Easier? No. Redrawing everything is the easiest method. More efficient? Depends. Drawing will probably not be your bottleneck. Pygame supports updating only parts of the screen (r.g. with the `DirtySprite` and `LayeredDirty` classes), but usually it's just not worth it, especially with modern hardware (since calculating which parts of the screen to update costs performance, too. Also, if performance is crittical you should not use Python/Pygame, but for simple games it's good enough. For a simple Sudoku game, there's no point in wasting time thinking about performance optimization.

Answer (score -1):

The **safest** course is to re-paint the screen, even at 30fps/when nothing is changing.

Secondly, will modifying the code actually make a difference to the load on the PC?

The theme seems to be: if the Sudoku board hasn't changed, why bother? So, put the screen-update 'behind' the same condition which examines input. If the user instructs that a digit is to be inserted in a chosen-square (for example), and thus the appearance of the board is to be changed, then after updating the graphic(s)/sprite positions, the logic must call for a screen-update!

This will be slightly more complicated if you have also changed the mouse-pointer and must update the mouse's appearance as it is moved!

**Before** you do this, monitor the PC's performance graphs, then perform a Before-After analysis. It'll be interesting to read the results...

Regards =dn